# how to retrieve value from div

Tags: jquery

here is my html and jquery and when the page loads I'm supposed to get an alert box with the value 10 but instead i get nothing. what am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    val = $("#t").text();
    alert(val);

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="t">10</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try and always wrap your code to run when the `document` has the elements populated, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  val = $("#t").text();
  alert(val);
});
</script>
```

...otherwise when `$("#t")` runs to select `id="t"` elements it does run...but the elements aren't in the DOM to find yet.

Comment: If the page gets stuck for a while the script will be executed only later. Ex: if SO page doesn't fully load and you click the envelop it will not open, instead you will be redirected to stackexchange. Add a script tag after the element makes it execute immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML

```
<div id="t">10</div>
```

Is after the script, the script runs before finding nothing.

You have to change the order

```
<div />
<script />
```

Or use [`jQuery.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

**[Example on jsBin](http://jsbin.com/inepi5)**

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve something from an element that does not yet exist. The simplest solution is to move your JS code to the bottom of your HTML (right before the `</body>`).

Another solution is to "wrap" your code inside a jQuery [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event:

```
$( document ).ready ( function () {
    val = $("#t").text();
    alert(val);
} );
```

The ready event will trigger when the DOM is ready to be manipulated with.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
<div id="t">10</div>

val = $("#t").html();
    alert(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is executing before the div has been processed by the browser.

The div is not yet in the DOM.

You could either move the scrip tag to below the div or wrap you code in an on ready function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        val = $("#t").text();
        alert(val);
    });
</script>
```